# git で refs のコミットとしての差分を計算したい

Tags: git

git で、 merge-base などでいろいろスクリプトで revision を計算していると、ある (機械的に計算された) revision と別の revision の関係を、人目に確認したくなります。

revision をコミットの集合だと見立てて、このコミット集合としての差分が表示されるような、 diff のようなことができたらいいなと考えました。

例えば、 `git commit-diff A B` などやると、

```
-f4795c1
-e83d77e
-bb3071c
+6abda0a
+4abf1f2
+f63f014
```

と表示されるようなイメージです。 (- は A のみに存在するコミット, + は B のみに存在するコミット)

このようなことは実現できますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git rev-list --left-right A...B`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#git-rev-list---left-right) とすることで、Aからしか辿れないコミットは `<` を、Bからしかたどれないコミットは `>` を行頭につけて表示します。

```
$ git log --graph --format="%h %s %d" --all
* edf1e4a D'  (HEAD -> sub)
| * 596d9dc D  (master)
| *   97383f4 Merge branch 'sub'
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | c0beb50 C'
* | 15ca411 B'
| * 8089f66 C
| * b863214 B
|/
* 26a4b95 A

$ git rev-list --left-right --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit master...sub
>edf1e4a D'
<596d9dc D
<97383f4 Merge branch 'sub'
<8089f66 C
<b863214 B
```

ちなみに `--boundary` オプションを付けると共通するコミットも表示されますが、指定したコミットからさかのぼっていく形で探索するので、次の例で言うと `B'` は見えてないですね。

```
$ git rev-list --left-right --boundary --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit master...sub
>edf1e4a D'
<596d9dc D
<97383f4 Merge branch 'sub'
<8089f66 C
<b863214 B
-26a4b95 A
-c0beb50 C'
```

Answer (score -1):

ここの一番下のやつ

Commit Ranges - tripple dot

が参考になるかもしれません。

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection